# Write beyond program break

Tags: c, operating-system

Why is it possible to write beyond the current program break in the following program?

```
int main()
{
    sbrk(4095);

    void *addr = sbrk(0);
    printf("%p\n", addr);

    *(char*)(addr) = 'a';

    return 0;
}
```

If you change 4095 to 4096, then a seg fault will happen as expected. But 4095 works well. I'm almost sure that this relates to the pagesize (which is 4096 on my system). My guess is that, in the case of 4095, the `sbrk` call sets the entire page to be mappable so that a page is successfully mapped when the write happens to the last byte of that page.

But why that write is permitted (it's beyond the current program break)? Could someone give a more detailed explanation?

Comment: The kernel (and the hardware, i.e. the MMU) can only manage memory in page units. BTW, [sbrk(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html) is obsolete. See notes in the `man` page.

Comment: Then why not constrain the program break to be always page-aligned?

Comment: I think it's not entirely obsolete. For example, malloc still uses `sbrk` to allocate small pieces of memory, as shown in `man 3 malloc`.

Comment: @Cyker: That's part of the implementation, not the public function `sbrk`. The latter is 100% obsolete and very dangerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Basile Starynkevitch noted in the first comment, this is a hardware limitation: the "break" moves in units of pages.

This was true even on the original (swap-based) PDP-11 Unix systems, where the hardware protection unit was 8192 byte "pages" (not demand-paged pages, but still pages).

Nonetheless, the interface works in terms of bytes.  If you adjust the break into the middle of a page, then move it forward one byte at a time, the system call is basically an expensive no-op until you cross into the next page, at which point it maps that page.  This was true even on the original PDP-11 systems and there's no particular reason to forbid it today.